# android adding onclick events to parts of an image?

Tags: android

My layout file currently displays an image, but I would like clicking certain parts of the image to call different things, such as changing the content view/switching activities.  Is there a way to make an onClickListener for certain parts of the screen?

Comment: Yes you can add buttons over the image and make them transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an image map or you can use this [link](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/)